# What should I replace Hub control with in UWP app(s)

Tags: uwp-xaml

I am currently using a Hub control in several UWP apps, but recently found that it is no longer recommended for Win10 apps.  What control do you think I should replace it with?  Pivot?  or is there something better? (no ext. libraries or NuGet if possible).

Answer (score 0):

> What should I replace Hub control with in UWP app(s)

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub?view=winrt-19041#remarks) *For Windows 10 and later: We recommend against using this control; use one of the other navigation controls instead*.

If we use hub control to navigation, we could use [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) to replace. And if we use hub to display item, we could use [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview) to replace.

Even though, the document recommend against using this control, but it has not been been deprecated. So we could also use it in UWP platform.

Comment: Im looking for more of a 'in my experience, this was a good solution  I already read that doc, I'm wondering if a Pivot view or a Tab View or a navigation view would be the best replacement.

Comment: Sure, you could also use pivot and tab view as the navigation architecture.